# Pinging a server in C

Tags: c, networking, ping

I have a piece of code which pings a server:

```
int main(){
    if ( system( "ping 111.222.333.44") == 0 )
        printf("success");
    return 0;
}
```

The code prints the following:

```
PING 111.222.333.44 (111.222.333.44) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 111.222.333.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.565 ms
64 bytes from 111.222.333.44: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.874 ms
.
.
```

and so on. Since `success` is never printed, I assume that `system( "ping 111.222.333.44")` somehow enters an infinite loop. When I hit `Ctrl+C`, the statistics are printed (`min/avg/max/mdev` etc.) and the program terminates. Is there a way to avoid this infinite loop?

Also, is the number of bytes sent to the server is 56 or 84? Or 64? And can we specify this value manually? If I were to calculate the speed during the process, would I do `56 bytes / 0.565ms = 99.1 KB/s`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ping will continue to run indefenently without configuration - use `-c NUM` flag, where `num` is the number of packets to send

Answer (score 1):

In short, `ping` can be configured in many different ways. With `-c 4`, you can specify that 4 ping packets are sent, with `-s XX` you can specify the packet size.